# can anyone explain to me what does (content: "\f01a"; ) on css means? and how to use it?

Tags: html, css

can anyone explain to me what does **(content: "\f01a"; )** on css means? and how to use it?

I'm having a problem locating this icons on my css file, I don't know were to find it, I've tried searching some solutions on google but it only makes my self confuse.

if only someone could explain it to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mean: fa-arrow-circle-o-down. It's used with Font Awsome plugin for displaing ["font-icons".](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/) For use it you must read the documentation. 
CSS has a property called content. It can only be used with the pseudo elements :after and :before. It is written like a pseudo selector (with the colon), but it's called a pseudo element because it's not actually selecting anything that exists on the page but adding something new to the page.

[<< FOR MORE INFO >>](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/)

Answer (score 1):

With the content command, css will write the text which is given into the html element.
The \f01a is a Unicode Symbol in Hexadecimal. I think you have to embed a given font, so the icons will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

`content` property sets text to the element. It works with pseudo selectors only.
You can set any text.

It can be used to set icons.(icons but not images, using different fonts).

[More info here.](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/)

Answer (score 0):

These are content values for showing respective icons in your website.

You can use it like this,

```
.element:before {
  content: "\f01a"; 
 }
```